# UV Distortion - Correctable?

Tags: uv

This question has come up a few times on here and I have checked them for a partial answer to my question; as in WHY it does it. What I need to know is IF there is a solution to it that doesn't involve altering my UV map from a rectangle.

To make better use of texture space I am overlapping faces that will be sharing the same texture, and to make it easier for me to create the texture by keeping the UV's square where possible. I know this will 'pinch' the texture but this is the result I am looking for.

The problem is that distortion across the diagonal of each face. I know why it does it, I need to know if there is a work-around that doesn't involve altering the UV's from a 90 deg rectangle.

The only solution I've found is to subdivide a few times to make the effect less noticable, however this is a less than ideal solution as it increases the tris count. What I am making will go into a game so polys are everything.

Is there a way to achieve the result in the second image without resorting to what I had to do in the second image?

Thanks

[image: Without subdivide]

[image: With subdivide x2]

Comment: There is no other solution than to increase geometry or UV unwrap without distortion. As you don't want to do any of that, there is no solution for you. You can code your own game engine which does UV space mapping differently and then you won't have a problem. This engine will have very poor fps, you might be better just using more texture space.

Comment: @Jerryno We don't know which engine he is using. Chances of any single person making a better sampling algorithm than in the existing shader standards are slim. This problem is not caused by imperfect mapping code in the first place.

Comment: Diagonal distortion only happens when UV shape doesn't match the model shape, can't you do anything about it? I also recommend checking how the textures look in the target engine environment. Finally, if you need to add some subdivisions it's not the end of the world but you should also consider if it's possible to use the vertices for more expressive geometry.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Apologies I forgot to note the engine will be Unity.

Yes I can match the UV to the shape of the face(s) I was just hoping to not have to in order to make creating the texture as simple as I could.

I've elected to increase geometry in the end, upon doing a little more research on the target game engine and specifically the game it is intended for.

As the object I am creating is classed as a unique building, IE not one that is automatically and repeatedly spawned within game, I have a lot more leeway with tris count.

Thanks again.